# What happens if too many student withdraw from a course

Tags: united-states, undergraduate

I am taking a four week online summer course in the U.S. and the professor just canceled it because all but me and one other student (out of 30+ students) withdrew from the class within the first week. I guess the minimum for the class is 20 students. Is this normal? I'm not sure yet but I think we get our money back for the course, I just am not sure if it is standard for this to happen. and if so what happens on my transcript?

Answer (score 4):

Courses are sometimes cancelled due to low enrollment. Usually this happens during the first week to allow the students to transfer to a different course. Since this is before the "drop" deadline, the course does not appear on the student transcript and no tuition is charged.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, there should be no charge for a course not delivered, nor any effect on the transcript.

But, in addition to enrolling in "another course" one option is to request an independent study from that professor. That might be possible or not and the other student might also be interested. But it is worth an effort to ask.

---

Yes, I realize the question is very old, but others might have a similar question in future.